# Which program am I using to lock screen?

Tags: 14.04, xfce, lock-screen, screensaver

On Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE desktop environment, how can I know which program or daemon is locking my screen automatically after a few minutes of inactivity, and when I click "lock screen"? Different users on the computer are obviously using different screensavers / locking programs. In my account when I start xscreensaver I get a warning that gnome screen saver daemon is running. However when I run gnome-screensaver-command -q the output is "The screensaver is inactive".

Comment: Well going to TTY and investingating processes with `ps -ef | grep 'screensaver'` is a start

Comment: good point! I see three things: 1) light-locker --lock-after-screensaver=10 --no-lock-on-suspend --late-locking  2)  xscreensaver -no-splash 3) /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon.  So I guess light-locker is in charge.

Comment: Yup, and probably they are listed for different users, light-locker and gnome-screensaver is most likely root-owned, and probably is spawned by gnome or unity.   I'd expect xscreensaver to be for your user , unless it set to start at boot somewhere.

Comment: @Serg You might want to post that as answer? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not detect all screensavers but it worked for me:

```
ps -ef | grep 'screensaver'
```